# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Constants error in react-native app on android only in ios work fine

Tags: react-native, expo

im facing an anoying issue with a react native code : running the app on expo app on ios work fine but on android it shows the following error ! im not sure where the issues is but the constants variable is imported as it should can you help me identify what generate the error :

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Constants
>
> This error is located at:
>       in Index (created by Connect(Index))
>       in Connect(Index) (created by SectionData)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in SectionData (created by ListingDetail)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
>       in ScrollView (created by AnimatedComponent)
>       in AnimatedComponent (created by ListingDetail)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in ListingDetail (created by Connect(ListingDetail))
>       in Connect(ListingDetail) (created by Index)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Handler (created by Index)
>       in Index (created by Connect(Index))
>       in Connect(Index) (created by PostDetailScreen)
>       in PostDetailScreen (created by withSafeArea)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in AnimatedComponent (created by SafeView)
>       in SafeView (created by withOrientation)
>       in withOrientation (created by withSafeArea)
>       in withSafeArea (created by Connect(withSafeArea))
>       in Connect(withSafeArea) (created by SceneView)
>       in SceneView (created by TabNavigationView)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in ResourceSavingScene (created by TabNavigationView)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in ScreenContainer (created by TabNavigationView)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in TabNavigationView (created by NavigationView)
>       in NavigationView (created by Navigator)
>       in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
>       in NavigationContainer (created by RootRouter)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in AndroidDrawerLayout (created by DrawerLayoutAndroid)
>       in DrawerLayoutAndroid (created by MenuAndroid)
>       in MenuAndroid (created by Connect(MenuAndroid))
>       in Connect(MenuAndroid) (created by RootRouter)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RootRouter (created by Connect(RootRouter))
>       in Connect(RootRouter) (created by App)
>       in Provider (created by App)
>       in App (created by withSafeArea)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in AnimatedComponent (created by SafeView)
>       in SafeView (created by withOrientation)
>       in withOrientation (created by withSafeArea)
>       in withSafeArea (created by ExpoRootComponent)
>       in RootErrorBoundary (created by ExpoRootComponent)
>       in ExpoRootComponent
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in RootSiblingsWrapper (created by AppContainer)
>       in RCTView (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in AppContainer componentWillMount
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:288151:65
>   callComponentWillMount
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:14755:38
>   mountClassInstance
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:14843:33
>   updateClassComponent
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:16298:31
>   performUnitOfWork
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19003:27
>   workLoop
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19035:47
>   renderRoot
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19098:21
>   performWorkOnRoot
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19789:23
>   performWork
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19713:30
>   performSyncWork
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19688:20
>   batchedUpdates$1
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:19889:28
>   batchedUpdates
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:10963:37
>   _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:11020:23
>   receiveTouches
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:11050:34
>   __callFunction
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:3644:49
>   
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:3417:31
>   __guard
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:3598:15
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fmac%2FDesktop%2F11%2FListPro%201.3.1%205%2Fold%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles.js:3416:21
>   callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       [native code]

```
import {  Images, Events, Config, AppConfig, Tools, Constants} from '@common'

  this.isListable = AppConfig.Theme == Constants.Themes.Classic
    this.isMyListing = AppConfig.Theme == Constants.Themes.Classic
    this.isListingPro = AppConfig.Theme == Constants.Themes.Classic
```

Comment: Did you export 'Constants' ?

Comment: yes its declared as follow

    

'use strict'
import { Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native'

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default {



  Themes: {
    Classic: 'classic',
    Restaurant: 'restaurant',
  },

    
and its strange it's working in ios but not in android

Comment: any help would be apreciated

Comment: Got a similar error after failing to `import {Constants} from 'expo'`